# High Charts - Populating Data From Array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was wondering if anyone could see why my code for high charts isn't working? I have been trying to fix it for ages and I cant get it to work. I looked at this question [Populate JSON object to highchart bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822588/populate-json-object-to-highchart-bar-chart) for help but cant get my code to work.

```
    <?php 
    include('../connection.php');
    $selectCategory = "SELECT CategoryName, COUNT( fkDiaryCategory ) as count
    FROM    `tbldiary`, tbldiarycategories where pkCategory=fkDiaryCategory group by fkDiaryCategory";

    $catResult = mysqli_query($conn,$selectCategory);

    $tableRows = array();
    $i=0;
    while($dataRow = mysqli_fetch_array($catResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $tableRows[$i]['CategoryName']=$dataRow['CategoryName'];
    $tableRows[$i]['count']=$dataRow['count'];
    $i++;
     };
     $data = (json_encode($tableRows));
     ?> 
    <script>

    var data = '<?php echo $data ?>';
    console.log(data);
    $(function() {
        // Populate series
        var processed_json = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            processed_json.push([parseInt(data[i].count),data[i].CategoryName]);
        }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // draw chart
        var options={
            chart: {

               renderTo: 'container',                   
                type: "column"
            },
            title: {
                text: "Diary Entries by Category"
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: data.CategoryName,
                title: {
                    text: "CategoryName"
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
              min:0,
                title: {
                    text: "Total"
                }
            },
            series: data
        };

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
</script>
  <div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my lecturer helped with the while loop populating the processed_json array, and Im not 100% sure if this is needed but I left it in just incase. Thanks in advance!

Edited to add:

The data I am putting in looks like this when you do console.log
[{"CategoryName":"Home life worries","count":"2"},{"CategoryName":"Social life worries","count":"2"},{"CategoryName":"Exam stress","count":"1"},{"CategoryName":"University life stress","count":"1"},{"CategoryName":"Work stress","count":"1"}]

Comment: $data = json_encode($tableRows); now check

Comment: @SRK I assume you are talking about two lines above where the <script> starts? Tried that, didn't work...

Comment: what you got in view share it

Comment: you have take categoryname seperate

Comment: @SRK I'm not sure how to share that? Its just coming up as a blank chart with tonnes of series below - although the series aren't relevant to whats in the array at all

Comment: you category should [{'CateforyName':'Home life worries', and so on}]

Comment: got ya! Il try that now

Comment: @SRK OK so I have done that, and I now have two arays, data and CatData which look like this [{"CategoryName":"Home life worries","count":"2"},{"CategoryName":"Social life worries","count":"2"},{"CategoryName":"Exam stress","count":"1"},{"CategoryName":"University life stress","count":"1"},    {"CategoryName":"Work stress","count":"1"}]
dashboardDiaryStats.php:23 ["Home life worries","Social life worries","Exam stress","University life stress","Work stress"]   but still nothing has changed

Comment: have try  with  highchart  demo

Comment: what type of chart are you using

Comment: The format of data that you have should work completely fine, you don't have to change it to what SRK suggested. The reason it doesn't work is because Highcharts does not understand the keys "CategoryName" and "count". If you change "CategoryName" to just "name" and "count" to "y", your problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is as you posted in comments, then you are parsing data for series and not series itself. If you set name for each point, then setting `category` type for xAxis will force chart to use points' names as categories.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7nLz2b8d/1/

```
var data = [{
  "CategoryName": "Home life worries",
  "count": "2"
}, {
  "CategoryName": "Social life worries",
  "count": "2"
}, {
  "CategoryName": "Exam stress",
  "count": "1"
}, {
  "CategoryName": "University life stress",
  "count": "1"
}, {
  "CategoryName": "Work stress",
  "count": "1"
}];

$(function() {
  // Populate series
  var processed_json = [],
      len = data.length;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    processed_json.push([data[i].CategoryName, parseInt(data[i].count)]);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // draw chart
    var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: "column"
      },
      title: {
        text: "Diary Entries by Category"
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title: {
          text: "CategoryName"
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: "Total"
        }
      },
      series: [{
        data: processed_json
      }]
    };

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

  });
});
```

Comment: This works!!! Thank you! Although, do you know if there is a way to change it so that instead of hard coding the var data information, I can just have it coming from the database so that its dynamic? Does that make sense

Comment: @Anon Load your data instead of hard-coding it before parsing it and building your chart. More about working with data can be found in HC Docs: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code
[And hole example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative)

```
 $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Column chart with negative values'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Im just trying to manipulate my data to make it look like this!